# Issue with ArrayUtils Import: package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import

I just began studying something related to IT and have some projects I am working on.
With the most recent one, I have ran into a problem, fow hich I just cannot seem to find a solution.

I am using IntelliJ to code Java and for a certain piece of code I want to use "ArrayUtils.removeElement", for which I need to import ArrayUtils:
"import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;"

[Import Issue regarding ArrayUtils in IntelliJ Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O44B2.png)

As you can see in the reference image, the second line gives me an error. I just can't import it for some reason.

Thank you in advance!!

I have already tried to invalidate Caches, but to no result.

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Looks like you are missing the (right) dependency. I suggest taking a look at dependency- and build-management-tools like [gradle (`gradle.org`)](https://gradle.org/) or [maven (`maven.apache.org`)](https://maven.apache.org/).

Comment: Please, do not post images of code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to declare the dependency to the commans-lang3 artifact.

You could do it with any dependency management system like maven, gradle ...

You can find the latest version of commons-lang3 in mvn central:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0

If you don't know about maven (or any other tool) you can manually add the dependency to your project.

Via IntelliJ mvn downloader.

File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> Add -> Maven
[image]

or download the jar file directly and add it with intelliJ

[commons-lang3.jar](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0/commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar)

and add it with

File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> Add -> Java -> Select the jar